# Merging two separated parts back into one perfectly

Tags: mesh, objects

[image]I have a spherical-like object whose thickness is 1.6 mm.  There is a section of the surface that is to be only 0.8 mm thick.  So I changed the thickness of the entire object to 0.8 mm, then selected the faces that define that special region, then pressed P to separate it from the rest of the object, then changed the entire object's thickness back to 1.6 mm.  So now that special region is 0.8 mm as desired.  The problem now is the gap between that region and the rest of the surface caused by the separation.  I want to close that gap so that from the outside, the surface looks like a single surface and no one can tell where the 0.8 mm thick region is.  What is the most precise way to do this?

I tried moving the edges and vertices of the region so that it intersects with the original surface, but the intersection is not clean (see below).  How to do it perfectly so that it looks like the original surface from the outside?
[image]

When I join the two with Ctrl+J, the two regions share the same edges, so I'm stuck on how to proceed there as well.
[image]

Comment: Am I mistaken to say there is a subdivision modifier involved here with the model you are working on? Have you tried to remove doubles after you Join the 2 pieces together with Cltr + J?

Comment: @hawkenfox  Joining with Ctrl + J makes the two regions have the same thickness again (I tried it), when my goal is to have the different regions with different thicknesses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried smooth vertex?

1. Select mesh
2. Edit Mode
3. Select these vertices/faces
4. select smooth vertex from the tools panel

**UPDATE:**

Another way to do this is adding the thickness to the opposite direction by flipping the face normals and then adding thickness using the solidify modifier. This will add thickness internally so that the original mesh is not messed up as shown below:

I split the sphere into upper and lower half:
[image]

I then switched to edit mode and flip normals:
[image]

Then add the solidify modifier with the desired thickness and apply it:
[image]

as shown I added thickness -0.8 which was added internally.

I then joined the two meshes:

[image]

As shown the lower half has more thickness than the upper half.

I wrote the below script to do these steps between two meshes automatically:

```
import bpy

ob = bpy.data.objects['Sphere.001']
ob.select = True
bpy.context.scene.objects.active = ob
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
bpy.ops.mesh.flip_normals()
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='SOLIDIFY')
bpy.context.object.modifiers["Solidify"].thickness = 0.8
bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(apply_as='DATA', modifier="Solidify")
ob2 = bpy.data.objects['Sphere']
ob2.select = True
bpy.ops.object.join()
```

A blend file can be downloaded from here:
[image]

Comment: No, I didn't.  But when I try it now, it does not seem to remove the gap but merely deform the gap.

Comment: It will smooth the vertices in this area and should do what you want. Like you keep smoothing these vertices until you get the desired smooth surface.

Comment: Ok.  Let's say your method does work.  Then it is still a manual sculpting-like solution that will never give the perfect solution I seek (automated and appearing as though nothing was ever done to the surface to begin with).

Comment: Well, could you provide your .blend file to have a better look?

Comment: I don't know how to attach .blend files here, but one can just take a UV sphere.  Separate a region of the sphere from the rest of the sphere (optionally, change its thickness like I did).  And then see if you can join it back to look like nothing ever happened.

Comment: I don't see another way to do it automatically rather than smoothing the vertices, which can be done through python. Wanting to join two separate meshes to fit exactly automatically is kinda not possible, to my knowledge at least. Have you tried smoothing the vertices? Also what is your scenario? If you are splitting a mesh and then want to rejoin it, then why split it from the beginning?

Comment: My original post describes how I wanted one region to be thinner than the rest of the region (but I want this to not be visible from outside the surface, hence joining them back together again).

Comment: you can upload your file as shown here http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/658/including-a-blend-file/659#659

Comment: @prestokeys I've updated my answer with a better way, adding thickness internally to the mesh instead of externally and wrote a script for the process to be done automatically.

Comment: This is very exciting!  I don't understand how to use the code you wrote, but I will try your method with my object.  If it works, I will accept your answer.

Comment: @prestokeys, just open the text editor and paste my script then hit the run script button. Check this https://youtu.be/K0yb4sZ7B4g?t=9

Comment: @prestokeys I've added a .blend file to the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50874/discussion-between-prestokeys-and-tak).